# Is there any way to validate each column of ANT DESIGN Table indiviually?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, validation

What I am doing is that I am rendering data in ant design table, and each column of each row is editable now when wrong data is rendered for example email is in bad format there should be validation message down to email that email is not valid & when user start typing I also need to validate user input also that was for editing. like when the user starts typing I also need to validate each input change either it is right email or wrong, similarly, I need to use custom regex for each column of the row, I hope I tried my best to collaborate the problem what I am facing.

What I tried soo far is below.

1 - When Data is rendered to the table I got two editable columns for each row.
[Data is rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NTCe.png)

2 - When User Start Editing 
[User Editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDCgi.png)

3 - Validation Is failed when the text box is empty my objective is to validate each keystroke also, either the email is correct or not that is being entered when validation pass error goes away.
 [Validation Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1dmb.png)

Below is the code I tried soo far

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Input, Button, Popconfirm, Form } from "antd";

const EditableContext = React.createContext();

const EditableRow = ({ index, ...props }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
        <tr {...props} />
      </EditableContext.Provider>
    </Form>
  );
};

const EditableCell = ({
  title,
  editable,
  children,
  dataIndex,
  record,
  handleSave,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const form = useContext(EditableContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [editing]);

  const toggleEdit = () => {
    setEditing(!editing);
    form.setFieldsValue({
      [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex]
    });
  };

  const save = async e => {
    try {
      const values = await form.validateFields();
      toggleEdit();
      handleSave({ ...record, ...values });
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log("Save failed:", errInfo);
    }
  };

  let childNode = children;

  if (editable) {
    childNode = editing ? (
      <Form.Item
        style={{
          margin: 0
        }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `${title} is required.`
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input ref={inputRef} onPressEnter={save} onBlur={save} />
      </Form.Item>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
        style={{
          paddingRight: 24
        }}
        onClick={toggleEdit}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <td {...restProps}>{childNode}</td>;
};

class EditableTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.columns = [
      {
        title: "name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        width: "30%",
        editable: true
      },
      {
        title: "age",
        dataIndex: "age",
        editable: true
      },
      {
        title: "address",
        dataIndex: "address"
      },
      {
        title: "operation",
        dataIndex: "operation",
        render: (text, record) =>
          this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
            <Popconfirm
              title="Sure to delete?"
              onConfirm={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)}
            >
              <a>Delete</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          ) : null
      }
    ];
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [
        {
          key: "0",
          name: "Edward King 0",
          age: "32",
          address: "London, Park Lane no. 0"
        },
        {
          key: "1",
          name: "Edward King 1",
          age: "32",
          address: "London, Park Lane no. 1"
        }
      ],
      count: 2
    };
  }

  handleDelete = key => {
    const dataSource = [...this.state.dataSource];
    this.setState({
      dataSource: dataSource.filter(item => item.key !== key)
    });
  };

  handleAdd = () => {
    const { count, dataSource } = this.state;
    const newData = {
      key: count,
      name: `Edward King ${count}`,
      age: 32,
      address: `London, Park Lane no. ${count}`
    };
    this.setState({
      dataSource: [...dataSource, newData],
      count: count + 1
    });
  };

  handleSave = row => {
    const newData = [...this.state.dataSource];
    const index = newData.findIndex(item => row.key === item.key);
    const item = newData[index];
    newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
    this.setState({
      dataSource: newData
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;
    const components = {
      body: {
        row: EditableRow,
        cell: EditableCell
      }
    };
    const columns = this.columns.map(col => {
      if (!col.editable) {
        return col;
      }

      return {
        ...col,
        onCell: record => ({
          record,
          editable: col.editable,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          title: col.title,
          handleSave: this.handleSave
        })
      };
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={this.handleAdd}
          type="primary"
          style={{
            marginBottom: 16
          }}
        >
          Add a row
        </Button>
        <Table
          components={components}
          rowClassName={() => "editable-row"}
          bordered
          dataSource={dataSource}
          columns={columns}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<EditableTable />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

[LINK TO CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/editablecellentdesign-vlgdo)

MY OBJECTIVE :

1 - When Data is rendered I need validation there as if the email is not correct then there will be valid for that invalid email.

2 - When the user starts typing it validates Keystore when the email is correct validation goes away.

3 - There will be more columns like phone, address there will be regex I need to validate each column in each row separately using regex.

I tried my best to describe my problem anything else I can provide tell me thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i just solve this problem by using switch case statement in my editablecell function as below

```
 EditableCell = ({
    title,
    editable,
    children,
    dataIndex,
    record,

    ...restProps
  }) => {
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const form = useContext(EditableContext);
    useEffect(() => {
      if (editing) {
        inputRef.current.focus();
      }
    }, [editing]);

    const toggleEdit = () => {
      setEditing(!editing);
      form.setFieldsValue({
        [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex]
      });
    };

    let childNode = children;

    if (editable) {
      switch (dataIndex) {
        case "cName":
          {
            if (editing) {
              childNode = (
                <Form.Item
                  style={{
                    margin: 0
                  }}
                  name={dataIndex}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,

                      message: "Enter Name Please"
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    onChange={e => {
                      this.onChangeExelField(
                        record.key,
                        "cName",
                        e.target.value
                      );
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              );
            } else {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        case "cEmail":
          {
            if (editing) {
              childNode = (
                <Form.Item
                  style={{
                    margin: 0
                  }}
                  name={dataIndex}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      type: "email",
                      message: "Enter Valid Email Address"
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    onChange={e => {
                      this.onChangeExelField(
                        record.key,
                        "cEmail",
                        e.target.value
                      );
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              );
            } else if (
              !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(childNode[1])
            ) {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24,
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    border: "red solid 1px"
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        case "cPhone":
          {
            if (editing) {
              childNode = (
                <Form.Item
                  style={{
                    margin: 0
                  }}
                  name={dataIndex}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      pattern: new RegExp("^3[0-9+]{9}$"),
                      message: "Enter Correct Phone ( 3xxxxxxxxx )"
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    onChange={e => {
                      this.onChangeExelField(
                        record.key,
                        "cPhone",
                        e.target.value
                      );
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              );
            } else if (!/^3[0-9+]{9}$/i.test(childNode[1])) {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24,
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    border: "red solid 1px"
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        case "cAddress":
          {
            if (editing) {
              childNode = (
                <Form.Item
                  style={{
                    margin: 0
                  }}
                  name={dataIndex}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      pattern: new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 _/#&+-||]{25,}$"),
                      message: "Address Must be 25 letters"
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    onChange={e => {
                      console.log(record);
                      this.onChangeExelField(
                        record.key,
                        "cAddress",
                        e.target.value
                      );
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              );
            } else if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _/#&+-||]{25,}$/i.test(childNode[1])) {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24,
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    border: "red solid 1px"
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        case "cCity":
          {
            if (editing) {
              const options = [];
              this.props.cities.fetchedCities.docs.map(p => {
                options.push({ value: p._id, label: p.cityName });
              });

              childNode = (
                <Form.Item
                  style={{
                    margin: 0
                  }}
                  name={dataIndex}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Select
                    ref={inputRef}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={e => {
                      this.onChangeExelField(record.key, "cCity", e.label);
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              );
            } else if (record.invalidFields.includes("cCity")) {
              const options = [];
              this.props.cities.fetchedCities.docs.map(p => {
                options.push({ value: p._id, label: p.cityName });
              });
              childNode = (
                <div>
                  <Select
                    ref={inputRef}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={e => {
                      console.log(e);
                      this.onChangeExelField(record.key, "cCity", e.label);
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        case "cAmount":
          {
            if (editing) {
              childNode = (
                <Form.Item
                  style={{
                    margin: 0
                  }}
                  name={dataIndex}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,

                      message: "Enter Valid Amount"
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    onChange={e => {
                      this.onChangeExelField(
                        record.key,
                        "cAmount",
                        e.target.value
                      );
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              );
            } else {
              childNode = (
                <div
                  className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                  style={{
                    paddingRight: 24
                  }}
                  onClick={toggleEdit}
                >
                  {children}
                </div>
              );
            }
          }
          break;

        default:
          return null;
      }
    }

    return <td {...restProps}>{childNode}</td>;
  };
```